# HTML template to Javascript String Literals

Tags: javascript, string, literals

thanks for any feedback...

I have an HTML template with JS string literals embedded...

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   User name: ${user.name}
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm then doing...

```
let temp = require('./template.html')

return temp; // <--- I need this to return the compiled html
```

How can I get the string literals to render?

Is it even possible to do this?

I need the 'temp' variable to return as a compiled string so that I can insert it to a document.write later on in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) to turn it into a string template

```
return new Function("title","user","return `" + temp + "`;")(title,user);
```

As pointed out by T.J you will need to know all the variables used in the template and include them as arguments to the function.

Comment: Don't use `new Function()` that's almost as bad as `eval`

Comment: Of course, this presupposes knowing the names `title` and `user`.

Comment: why wouldn't I use new Function() here if the temp and the data have been sanitized?

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't string literals. They look like tokens in JavaScript's template literals.

> Is it even possible to do this?

If you mean that you want to load the HTML dynamically and then use it as a template literal, you only have two choices for doing that:

- Use a templating library (or write your own templating code) that parses the string and handles those tokens
- Use `eval` / `new Function`

`eval` (or `new Function`) is not evil **when used with your own content** (and performance costs have been *vastly* overstated), though I'm not saying I'd recommend it. But this is how you'd do it (assuming that in your stack, `require('./template.html')` will give you a string with the contents):

```
let temp = require('./template.html');
const template = "`" + temp.replace(/`/g, "\\`") + "`";
```

(There may be more escaping you want to do there, I just handled backticks.)

Then when you have the relevant tokens in scope:

```
const str = eval(template);
```

Live Example:

```js
let temp = document.getElementById("template").textContent.trim();
const template = "`" + temp.replace(/`/g, "\\`") + "`";

// Using it
const title = "This is the title";
const user = {name: "Joe Blogs"};
const str = eval(template);
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<html>
  <head>
   <title>${title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   User name: ${user.name}
  </body>
</html>
</script>
```

---

Why `eval` instead of `new Function` above? So that the code wrapping up the template for use doesn't have to know the names `title` and `user`. `new Function` still allows arbitrary code execution, just like `eval`, so you still can't use it except on your own content...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with some minor modification to your code.
First rename `template.html` to `template.js` and change its content to

```
exports default ({title, user}) =>`
    <html>
       <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
       </head>
       <body>
         User name: ${user.name}
       </body>
    </html>`
```

Then `let temp = require('./template.js')` will assign a function to temp that you should call with your context. Something like

```
let ctx = { title: 'titre', user: { name: 'alice' } }
let compiled = temp(ctx) // your compiled template
```

Check out [yo-yo](https://github.com/maxogden/yo-yo) a library that works around this concept